# UWF uwfmgr.exe doesn't do anything

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-administration, uwf, uwfmgr

Bear with me please, since I don't know that much about Windows – I'm trying to set up UWF (Unified Writing Filter) here on my mac through a Parallels installation of Windows 10. I found out how to enable UWF through the Control Pane, which I did. I then restarted the Virtual Machine. When I then tried to configure it through the powershell or command prompt (both run in admin mode), I got no response whatsoever. The uwfmgr.exe is there under c:\windows\system32, but like I said, it doesn't do anything when I run it. No response – but also, no error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by downloading the latest ISO for  10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a Windows 10 Enterprise edition for this to work. Just re-activating windows with an Enterprise key makes uwfmgr.exe print stuff again. Just testing, whether it works as well.

This was tested on Windows 10, V1809.